# Implementing RealmModel interface while extending another object

Tags: java, realm

I want to use the new feature of realm-java, where I can just implement RealmModel interface and add @RealmClass annotation to define a table. Everything works fine, until I try to extend some class. I get this error during compile time:

```
Realm model classes must either extend RealmObject or implement RealmModel to be considered a valid model class
```

I tried to add the annotation and implement RealmModel on the super class, but no effect.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like you are trying to make Polymorphism between your Realm's Object. (if not please add your model)

[This issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761) may probably interest you!